# how to avoid spark reexecution of expensive operations on each action

Tags: apache-spark

Here is app flow:

1. Read DB in 20 partitions. I have millions of rows. Data in dB is in blob format. so its size is unknown
2. in `mapPartition`, I loop through the records, convert the blob to JSON tabular format (expensive operation)
3. in a `foreachPartition`, using an accumulator I calculate the size of each partition using the data in JSON string length. Please note that using an accumulator on step2 does not work, always returns zero, so I have an accumulator inside foreach partition as the next step.
4. If DataSize in each partition > 1 GB, I repartition
5. Save the JSON tabular data to CSV file on disk.

The issue I am seeing is the expensive operation in step 2 is repeated twice, once when I do a `foreachPartition`, and another time when I do a save. I understand why spark does it twice. Question is how do I optimize this flow such that I avoid the expensive operations of step2 from repeating twice? How can I avoid repartition. I have the data in the 20 partitions in executor cores? Can I just split my dataset by size in these executors and save the csv file instead of repartition?

Comment: Hi, have you tried applying .cache() or .persist() after the action of .foreachPartition() ? this way you should avoid spark recalculating the result several times up to that point

Comment: The data is so huge that persist or cache is causing a performance dent.

Comment: for instance for a sample dataset of 5000 records, the spark app takes close to 3 mins without step3. With step3, it takes 5 mins, when I added a cache/persist, it took 8 mins.

Comment: So show the code and DAG, not sure why if part of same ACtion it would re-execute.

Comment: @Roja check out [AQE shuffle partitions feature](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalescing-post-shuffle-partitions) - you should be able to define a large number of shuffle partitions for Spark, and then during runtime AQE will coalesce these into a smaller number of partitions (according to the target size that you want to get) while checking the actual size of the partitions.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? It might be possible to refactor your code to avoid repeating the expensive operation twice.

Comment: Hi Oli, thats a great idea. The issue I have is my initial number of partitions is limited by dbthreads. When I read the table in step 1, I specify NumberOfPartitions to 20. This DB is also used to transaction applications, so I have to limit by threads to 10-20.  So when I start I am already limited to 200 partitions. If I repartition this wont I be moving data across machines? Is that efficient? I am new to spark, so I could be missing something

Comment: sorry the above comment was addressed to yishaiz.

Comment: Hi @Oli, bluephantom, will share the DAG to the above post and a reproducible example shortly

Comment: @Roja Sounds like you already repartition, so my suggestion can save you all the hassle of steps #3 and #4 by letting Spark do that for you. I didn't get you saying "when I start I am already limited to 200 partitions" is it because of the default shuffle partitions? you can change that. Repartition should be avoided when possible, that's correct. Now that I reread your question I understand that maybe your data fits inside each executor with 20 partitions,and you want to write smaller CSV files? You can do that in each task if you write the CSV inside the Task on your own and not by Spark API

Comment: Hi yishaiz, yes, thats correct. I have 20 partitions, need to write smaller csv files, if one csv file size > 1GB. Currently my data is in json format. So I was letting spark to the conversion from json to csv and store. I willt ry your idea to convert json to csv using spark, but save using plain java and not spark. thank you